# How to configure apache (+ajp?) with tomcat example.com domain and php blog.example.com subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, proxy, tomcat, ajp

I've been searching for a solution online for quite some time but can't seem to find a decent answer, so I might try my luck here...

I'm trying to configure apache+tomcat so that my domain example.com is mapped to a tomcat webapp.
This is the easy part and I figured out I can accomplish this via:

```
ProxyPass /site ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/site
ProxyPassReverse /site ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/site
```

I can also access my tomcat itself (to deploy apps etc) via:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
```

But what if I want my blog.example.com subdomain to be mapped to a wordpress instance?
I really can't figure out how to accomplish this, while this is quite a basic setup I assume.

All tips and comments are appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would add another virtual host for blog.xxx.com , and set all you need to use your wordpress instance. So you have one vhost for xxx.com (with ajp and all stuff like that) and  another for blog.xxx.com.

Answer (score 1):

Ruslan is right, you need separate virtual servers e.g. a virtualHost block with a specific Servername directive, and then it's own reverse proxy directives.